# Problem with Firefox and multiple <audio> and <video> elements on one page

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-video, html5-audio

I feel that now I've researched and unsuccessfully tried enough that I can ask you all a question.

###### Objective

As a non-pro developer with somewhat robust coding experience I'm building a website to be a diary for my beginning musical endeavours. I like it to be a bare-bones, manually maintained, vanilla HTML+CSS+JS one-pager where I can just drop in new recordings as they come. You can see the site here: http://thick.miami

The page is super simply structured as a main wrapper into which I add a `figure` element for each new recording. The figures contain the `audio` element held in a wrapper div, as well as a wrapped `video` element that works as a small visual. HTML diagrammatically like so:

```
<div id="Wrapper">

    <figure id="REC-1">
        <div class="audio-container">
            <audio />
        </div>
        <div class="video-container">
            <video />
        </div>
    </figure>

  <figure id="REC-2">
    ...
  </figure>

  ...

</div>
```

The videos are CSS-hidden at first, and then revealed with JS once a track starts playing, and hidden again when playback is paused on the current track, or started on another one. Currently there are 19 recordings = 19 audios + 19 videos in the page. Audios do not autoplay, videos do once they're constructed and displayed.

###### Problem

So far so good, and I get this to run smoothly in all browsers I've been checking *except for Firefox*. (I've been testing on FF, Chrome, Opera and Edge, on Windows and Android.) Here, it seems that the amount of media elements overwhelms the app at some point, basically corrupting display, playback and, indeed, (correct) loading of the elements.

###### Symptoms have been:

- Page load never finishes: page load progress bar remains visible and incomplete
- Audio tracks play unreliably: after a number of tracks have been started and paused again, further tracks drop out after a few seconds or won't start playing at all
- Videos don't load: after a numnber of tracks have been started and paused again, the videos of further tracks do not appear

###### What I have tried:

- Set preload to `preload="metadata"` and even `preload="none"` on all media elements to reduce memory/processing burden: no clearly discernible effect
- Remove CSS `padding` from `audio` elements, as appears to have been connected to a FF x media performance issue at some point: no effect
- Dynamically create the video elements with JS rather than hardcoding them in the HTML: this has helped FF from getting stuck in the page loading process but has not allayed the other issues
- Reduce video file size: no effect
- Clearing the page cache using `caches.delete()` on audio playback being stopped = videos getting hidden (this was a bit of a helpless attempt at giving FF more memory, for I guess at issue is not the cache but some other memory/processing resource beyond my coding competence): no effect

###### Hope

I do not like (and do not intend) to change the basic site structure and operation I have laid out. But I'm a FF lover and thus want it to work there flawlessly, and so I really hope that some of you have a pointer for how to fix this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How many audio/video elements do you have in the DOM? Are they all set to auto-play/preload? If so, it would be worth disabling those attributes

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan At this moment there's 19 recordings = 19 audios + 19 videos. Audios do not autoplay, videos do once they're constructed and displayed.

Comment: That's a lot, but I wouldn't say excessive. May be worth trying to disable preload too

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm only preloading metadata, though, so this wouldn't feel that it would be the problem, or?

Comment: Unlikely in that case, but worth a try. It's possible that Firefox's video rendering is poorly optimised and it just can't handle that many media elements in a single DOM.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Tried now to be sure - no help.